# How to decompose the Quantum Fourier Inverse matrix into elementary quantum gates?

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform

I am not sure how to find the following matrix (the inverse of Quantum Fourier Transform) in terms of elementary quantum gates? I am using Qiskit to implement it.

[image: Matrix for IQFT]

Answer (score 2):

Read the circuit for the QFT on 2 qubits and reverse and dagger everything

$$
(1 \otimes H)(Controlled(2,S_1^\dagger))(H \otimes 1)
$$

Edit:

For how: [Implementation of inverse QFT?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4875/implementation-of-inverse-qft/4877#4877)

This decomposition is $m=2$ on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform Note that $R_2 = S$

$1 \otimes H$ to denote Hadamard on the second qubit. $H \otimes 1$ for Hadamard on the first. $Controlled(2,S_1^\dagger)$ for use qubit 2 as the control and assuming that apply $S^\dagger$ on the first qubit.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the notation. By (1⊗H), do you mean applying a Hadamard gate to the first qubit? And I am not sure what (Controlled(2,S1)) means? Also, could you explain how you came up with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This might help you https://youtu.be/uuBgK44JrnA

Comment: Thank you! I have one last question, how can I represent the controlled-S† gate? I can only find a single-qubit S† gate.

Comment: if you're implementing using QISKit the video shows the code also.